# Can someone explain to me the Sequelize Join queries?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

can you tell us the sequel of the join queries I wrote below and why? There is no foreign key connection between models.

Example;

"SELECT * FROM users INNER JOIN posts ON users.id = posts.user_id";

"SELECT * FROM users INNER JOIN posts on users.id = posts.user_id WHERE posts.user_id = 5";

Comment: Sequelize queries doing SELECTs don't need any foreign keys. Foreign keys are needed for data consistency in DB. If you declare any associations between models you can associate any models if they have suitable fields to join to.

Comment: Can you make an example with above examples with sequelize?

Comment: Depends on what do you want to get: users with posts collection in each user or posts with a user object in each post

Comment: a post with user like this {postid:5,userid:10,user:{id:10,name:"anatoly"}}

Comment: Ok. Do you have model definitions?